# Udate Query with nested CASE statement in PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, nested, case

I have a nested SQL query for quiz example to update multiple tables. It contains of two **case** statements which check particular conditions while performing the query to DB. Here is the code:

```
// form data
$edit_qid = isset($_POST['editqid']);
$edit_question = isset($_POST['editquestion']);
$edit_ans1 = isset($_POST['editanswer1']);
$edit_ans2 = isset($_POST['editanswer2']);
$edit_ans3 = isset($_POST['editanswer3']);
$edit_correct = isset($_POST['editcorrect']);

// answer ids (comes from another query and it's valid)
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_aid)) {
    $aid[] = $rows['aid'];
}

// update of chosen question and answer options to DB
$upd_question = "UPDATE `question_bank` qtbl INNER JOIN `answer_bank` atbl
                        SET qtbl.`question`='".$edit_question."',
                            atbl.`answer`= CASE WHEN atbl.`aid`='".$aid[0]."' THEN '".$edit_ans1."'
                                                WHEN atbl.`aid`='".$aid[1]."' THEN '".$edit_ans2."'
                                                WHEN atbl.`aid`='".$aid[2]."' THEN '".$edit_ans3."' 
                                           END
                            atbl.`correct` = CASE WHEN ".$edit_correct."=='1' THEN '1'
                                                  WHEN ".$edit_correct."=='2' THEN '1'
                                                  WHEN ".$edit_correct."=='3' THEN '1' 
                                                  ELSE '0' 
                                             END
                    WHERE qtbl.`qid`=atbl.`question_id` AND qtbl.`qid`='".$edit_qid."'";
mysqli_query($mysqli, $upd_question) or die ("<b>Update of question failed:</b> " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

The variable `$edit_correct` contains either value 1, 2 or 3 with respect to answer strings and according to above mentioned query to DB there will be saved 1 or 0 (true/false) meaning that if value is 1 then true will be saved for 1st answer option etc.

Running of this code gives me the following error:

```
Update of question failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'atbl.`correct` = CASE WHEN 2=='1' THEN '1' WHEN 2=='2' THEN '1' ' at line 7
```

Any ideas to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Also, I checked with the following condition:

```
,atbl.`correct` = CASE WHEN '". if($edit_correct=='1') {echo 1;} ."' THEN '1'
                      WHEN '". if($edit_correct=='2') {echo 1;} ."' THEN '1'
                      WHEN '". if($edit_correct=='3') {echo 1;} ."' THEN '1' 
                      ELSE '0' 
                 END
```

and got this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)`

Comment: @RyanVincent But I have to check the value of `$edit_correct` whether it's 1 or 2 or 3 and then save proper true/false value in `correct` field of DB. Therefore I used '==' in case statement, however I'm not sure if it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put a comma betwen the two columns, try this code:

```
$upd_question = "UPDATE `question_bank` qtbl INNER JOIN `answer_bank` atbl
                        SET qtbl.`question`='".$edit_question."',
                            atbl.`answer`= CASE WHEN atbl.`aid`='".$aid[0]."' THEN '".$edit_ans1."'
                                                WHEN atbl.`aid`='".$aid[1]."' THEN '".$edit_ans2."'
                                                WHEN atbl.`aid`='".$aid[2]."' THEN '".$edit_ans3."' 
                                           END
                            ,atbl.`correct` = CASE WHEN ".$edit_correct."=='1' THEN '1'
                                                  WHEN ".$edit_correct."=='2' THEN '1'
                                                  WHEN ".$edit_correct."=='3' THEN '1' 
                                                  ELSE '0' 
                                             END
                    WHERE qtbl.`qid`=atbl.`question_id` AND qtbl.`qid`='".$edit_qid."'";
mysqli_query($mysqli, $upd_question) or die ("<b>Update of question failed:</b> " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

At the second case you can use IF() sentence, using IF will be more readable code.

Comment: I think adding of comma here doesn't make sense to the condition part, i.e. '==' however your suggestion of using IF() sentences inspired me to another approach (please have a look to UPDATE part of the question), but even that print error, i.e. parse error. Any ideas?

Comment: The first error you posted its for the comma in the Update, when you update more than one column they will separeted by commas, you left one between 'atbl.answer' and 'atbl.correct'.
About using if in the second case, try this:


,atbl.`correct` = IF(".$edit_correct." in ('1','2','3'), '1', '0')

Comment: But now it saves 1 (true) for all three answer options, which is not correct. I tried to split IF() sentence into 3 sentences, i.e.  `IF(".$edit_correct." in ('1'), '1', '0')` etc. it prints again a syntax error message. How to resolve that?

Comment: What values you want to save? Looking the first query you posted is the normal behaviour.
Maybe you have to open a new question.

Comment: The value `$edit_correct` contains one of the three (1 or 2 or 3) numbers, in case when it has `$edit_correct value 1` this means the value for correct field in DB for `$edit_ans1` (i.e. answer 1) should be saved as TRUE. The same applies for two others, i.e. `$edit_ans2` and `$edit_ans3`. I mentioned about that in my first question (it comes after the code).